# ASP.NET Core Multiple Projects with Individual User Accounts

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, session-cookies

I made a Project with two Web Applications using the Project Template "ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)".

Both of them are using the Option "Individual User Accounts" for Account- Management.

When I run both of them and log in to application1, the User that is currently logged on in application2 will be logged off and vice versa.

It seems that both Applications are using the same Cookie for Authentication.

How can I change this behaviour that logging into Application1 does not affect Application2, so that both Applications Accountmanagementsystems are separated from each other?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Brad added question.